# How to enable onclick type events with the output of a mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Tags: php, html, onclick

I have been trying to get my head around how to approach this problem.  I am writing a web page book library with the categories ('nodes') as MySQL records.  I want to print the list of categories at each level, starting at the highest level, and then allow the user to select a category to travel deeper into the library.  The PHP codes runs a saved procedure in MySQL:

```
//loop the result set

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

if ($row[1] <> 0) {  
  
    echo $row[0];
    echo "<br />";
} else {                                // the first row is just the heading

    "</strong>Category: ";        
    echo $row[0];
    echo " : <br />";
}}
```

Because there are only two test categories, this produces output:

```
Books :

Nature

Children's Books
```

However, I want to be able to create an onclick event over 'Nature' and 'Children's Books' so the user can select a category and drill down t the next level via a php function.  I can convert the php output into html eg:

```
 <?= "<p>{$row[0]}</p>" ?>
```

but I can't see how I can identify the row in an onclick event to pass a parameter to the function.  Perhaps I need to have a completely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` attribute to the element that calls a JavaScript function that does what you want.

```
<?= "<p onclick='someFunc({$row['id']})'>{$row[0]}</p>" ?>
```

Replace `id` with the actual name of the column containing the ID of the row in the table. `someFunc()` can use that ID to look up information in an array or object, or send an AJAX request.

Comment: fantastic! On this tonight!

Comment: I've been working on this but I'm struggling to understand how this line of code works.  (Forgive me but should there be a curly end bracket as shown here after the ['id']  <?= "<p onclick='someFunc({$row['id']})'>{$row[0]}</p>" ?>0).  But what does the > sign do?  Is it comparing the two variables and coming out with true or false?  Or does it mean something else.  I've searched the internet but can't find anything approximating it.

Comment: The `<>` are just the beginning and end of the `<p>` tags.

Comment: Yes, I was missing a `}`, that was just a typo.

Comment: Are you asking about `<?=` and `>?`? That was in your original code, and it's just the standard PHP sort tag. `<?=` is short for `<? php echo`

Comment: Ah! I get it now. Sometimes we think things are more complicated than they really are.  Thanks a lot Barmer - really appreciated!